# Import from Spreadsheet to Create List Fails in SharePoint 2010

Tags: spreadsheet

When I attempt to import an Excel Spreadsheet to create a list, it fails with a VB error:

> Automation error
>
> Catastrophic failure

Environment:
- SharePoint 2010
- SharePoint Designer 2010
- Visual Studio 2013
- Visual Studio 2012 Tools
- SharePoint Designer 2007 was installed, but I uninstalled it in case it was causing problems.

Actions Taken:

- Uninstalled SPD 2007
- Repaired SPD 2010 Install
- Repaired Office 2010 Install
- Reinstalled VB Runtime Library
- Edited EXPTOOWS.XLA in both 14hive and 15hive on my desktop.

  - I made the edit to change the value for lVe to 2.
  - I did not see an improvement so I reverted to the backup file I made.
- Confirmed alternate access mappings
- Confirmed IE security is set to low and intranet url is added

Since it breaks on the PublishToOWS function, it seems like it would be the EXPTOOWS.XLA, but I am not sure what is wrong.

[image: Error 1]
[image: Error 2]
[image: Error 3]